# In Celery, can we adjust how long finished tasks are stored in memory?

Tags: linux

Running Celery 4.3.0.
I want to be able to get the status of a task (via AsyncResult) many hours after it has finished. Say, 24 or 48 hours past success or failure.

Currently, I noticed the task object gets deleted a few hours after it has finished (can't tell exactly how many, but less than 24 hours).

Is it possible?

Thanks.